# Ошибка сегментации при захвате мьютекса

Tags: c, unix, pthread

Господа профессионалы, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может крыться подвох : мьютекс содержится в глобальной структуре, нормально инициализируется, нормально захватывается и освобождается потоками, но только несколько раз... Цикл, в котором происходит работа с данным мьютексом идентичный для всех дочерних потоков, проходит валидно 3-5 раз, при попытке очередного захвата *pthread_mutex_lock* генерирует *SIGSEGV*.

При разборе дампа в gdb ошибка сегментации по-прежнему вылезает при обращении к *pthread_mutex_lock*, но сильно сомневаюсь, что проблема в вызове. Напрямую отладчиком и valgrind-ом пока не подобраться, адреса, которые передаются в функцию - валидны, однако вылезла интригующая вещь - завела переменную в стеке потока, в цикле пару раз вывела ее адрес - он изменился... при этом значение переменной, присвоенное при создании потока сохранилось. Моет кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: В gdb запускали?

Comment: @dzhioev, нет пока, запуск под урезанной встраиваемой ОС, как только удастся залить туда gdb - попробую, пока отлаживаюсь по сообщениям журнала

Comment: Скорее всего память портитится.

В какую-нибудь статическую переменную (по адресам рядом с мьютексом) read(), strcmp() или что-то подобное не делаете ?

Comment: @avp, да, это наиболее вероятная причина, буду сейчас дамп делать и разбираться, но меня интересует, может ли возникнуть что-то подобное по другим причнам, например при переполнение потокового стека, и как это отследить

Comment: @margosh, Вы пишете об "урезанной встраиваемой ОС". Тут мне трудно говорить о причинах.


Вы адрес какой-нибудь переменной из стека потока распечатайте и сравните с адресами static данных. 

Еще можно попробовать переполнить стек какого-нибудь потока (например рекурсией) и посмотреть что будет (в смысле сигнала).

Comment: @avp, спасибо

Comment: Интересное поведение стека. Впервые слышу о таком, хотя теоретически можно представить. 

Попробуйте **все** перекомпилировать с -fPIC (но это чисто интуитивное предположение для gcc). Если не поможет, попробуйте мьютексы, их атрибуты и т.п. размещать в куче (malloc()).

@margosh, а что у Вас за система, если не секрет ?

Comment: @avp, FreeBSD. Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт. Все оказалось банально - *SIGSEGV* генерируется в случае, если поток захватывает блокировку и завершает свое выполнение, не освободив ее (в упор не замечала, что в проверке валидности аргументов функции в одной из веток разлочить мьютекс забыла). Все попытки искусственно переполнить стек потока рекурсией не увенчались успехом - никаких сигналов от ядра не поступало.